# How to loop through objects and assign them in-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i have array of objects and iterated through the object using the array function (map)
since we have the same key on all the objects not sure how to assign AA to 123, BB to 345 and CC to 555?
AA is a hardcoded value for 
Also the order of the object may change like first it may be {atr1:CC,atr2:555} then the following

Need some help to overcome this problem.

```
/*
{atr1: "AA", atr2: 123},
{atr1: "BB", atr2: 345}, 
{atr1: "CC", atr2: 555}
*/
const eList = ecom[0].esat.ttl 

return (
  {eList .map((list) => (
    <table class="greyGridTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>AA</td>
          <td>{iterated value 123}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>BB</td>
          <td>{iterated value 345}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CC</td>
          <td>{iterated value 555}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  ))}
)
```

Comment: What do `AA` and `BB` refer to? Are they variables you've declared? Or are they meant to be strings?

Comment: They are strings

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you return for each object in `eList` an entire table, i.e. three tables.

You only need to return the content of the `<tr>` for the "list" parameter via .map():

```
    return ( 
      <table class="greyGridTable">
        <tbody>
          {eList.map((list) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{list.atr1}</td>
              <td>{list.atr2}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
```

Comment: thank you. AA is hard-coded I don't want to take from object